# I have difference between Oracle sdo_geom.SDO_Distance and Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, sdo-geometry

```
SELECT sdo_geom.SDO_Distance (  
SDO_Geometry (2001, 4326, SDO_Point_Type ( -34.59593955425856, -58.43453386049867,null), null, null),  --  Parque Centenario
SDO_Geometry (2001, 4326, SDO_Point_Type ( -34.60643742373489, -58.376673444758225,null), null, null)  --  Obelisco
,1)
FROM dual;
```

-- Google Maps show: Distancia total: 5.10 km (3.17 mi)
-- Query returns: 6473,92625918709 m

Does anyone know why there is this difference?

Comment: related ellipsoidal vs spherical calculation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61892625/calculate-distance-between-two-lat-long-points-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

Oracle uses Longitude first, followed by latitude. The coordinates you have entered are swapped